# Can SELECT get different results within one transaction using Read Committed Isolation Level?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

So here is full paragraph from [postgresql 9.6 docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/transaction-iso.html) about Read Committed Isolation Level:

> Read Committed is the default isolation level in PostgreSQL. When a
>   transaction uses this isolation level, a SELECT query (without a FOR
>   UPDATE/SHARE clause) sees only data committed before the query began;
>   it never sees either uncommitted data or changes committed during
>   query execution by concurrent transactions. In effect, a SELECT query
>   sees a snapshot of the database as of the instant the query begins to
>   run. However, SELECT does see the effects of previous updates executed
>   within its own transaction, even though they are not yet committed.
>   Also note that two successive SELECT commands can see different data,
>   even though they are within a single transaction, if other
>   transactions commit changes after the first SELECT starts and before
>   the second SELECT starts.

---

So basically:

> SELECT query sees only data committed before the query began and never sees changes committed during query execution by
>   concurrent transactions.

But in last sentence it states that:

> Also note that two successive SELECT commands can see different data,
>   even though they are within a single transaction, if other
>   transactions commit changes after the first SELECT starts and before
>   the second SELECT starts.

For me it looks contradictory. Could someone elaborate that? How exactly two SELECT queries could see different data within one transaction? Isn`t transaction isolated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's true. To avoid such cases you need to use a higher isolation level: "repeatable read". 
Or even "serializable" if you need your transactions to be completely isolated.
Just keep in mind that higher isolation pays higher cost by means of performance.

Here you can find detailed explanation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html

So here is an example how could it happen:

1. Connection1 opens transaction and reads a row from Table1 with
   "select *"
2. Connection2 updates the same row and commits
3. Connection1 reads the same row again and gets updated data

The isolation level is "read committed", so literally everything commited becomes visible to other connections.

If you can not use a higher isolation level for some reason, there is a way to prevent such "unexpected" update from happening: your Connection1 can use "select ... for update" instead. This will effectively lock the row until transaction of Connection1 commits or rolls back. So Connection2 will wait for this commit or rollback to be able to update the row.

Comment: My main question is `How exactly two SELECT queries could see different data within one transaction?` and your answer does not really help

Comment: Just added an example, HTH. Please ask more detailed, if the above is not enough clear still.

Comment: So it means that transaction is not really isolated? It still can see commited changes by other transactions?

Comment: Potentially its isolated from uncommited changes but in postgresql its not possible to get those anyways

Comment: With READ_COMMITTED yes, isolated only from uncommitted changes. But still you can use REPEATABLE_READ (which is exactly about isolation you want) or even SERIALIZABLE (to exclude phantom reads as well).

Comment: I kind of like https://pgdash.io/blog/postgres-transactions.html for pointing out the subtle differences and its effects in clear examples rather than documentation. Might help others as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is no contradiction. Two consecutive SELECT statements within a transaction may fetch different results. Consider  this - you begin a transaction, then issue
select * from emp;
You get 2 records.
Another session inserts a record into emp and commits.
In the first session, you again issue 
select * from emp;
You get 3 records. This is expected behavior at READ COMMITTED isolation level.

Sample code

```
tmp=# begin ; 
BEGIN
tmp=# select * from emp;
 id 
----
  1
  2
(2 rows)

tmp=# select * from emp;
 id 
----
  1
  2
  3
(3 rows)

tmp=# commit;
```

Comment: Eh, it's pretty easy to get lost in reading that documentation and can totally lead to contradictions. In fact, before you even get into the nitty gritty of transactions, I'd consider calling transactions ACID is one of the biggest contradictions to start. 

I feel like people's assumption of what a transaction does by default would be the "Serializable" level.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer here 6 years after this question was asked because I got here trying to understand why the Postgres documentation seems to contradict itself.

The source of the confusion here is in the use of the words **query** and **transaction**.

The docs state that when a `SELECT` **query** starts, it sees only data that was committed before that **query** began. Note that it's referring to just the `SELECT` query itself, not to the whole **transaction**. One transaction may contain several queries.

So suppose you're running the query below in a transaction with read-committed isolation level:

```sql
SELECT name FROM users;
```

Suppose the `users` table is very large and your query is really complicated, so it takes a while to complete. While the `SELECT` is running, some other transaction does this:

```sql
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES ('John');
COMMIT;
```

What the Postgres docs are saying is that your first `SELECT` will never include `'John'` in the results because the query started before the second transaction committed. If you start a **new query** (even if you're within the same **transaction**), then you'll see `'John'` in the results.

If you cannot have `'John'` show up in any `SELECT` during a transaction, you'll need to use a higher isolation level (at the cost of reduced performance).